# Check same day in table

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have following data in my Attendance table:

```
Staff_ID  |       User_Attend_Date    |  Business_Day 
  S01     |   2013-05-01 15:18:45.537 |   2013-05-01  
  S01     |   2013-05-02 00:00:00.000 |   2013-05-01  
  S02     |   2013-05-03 06:20:30.225 |   2013-05-02
```

I want to display a new column to check whether the staff check-in date minus 3 hours is same day as business date.If same as business day,remain User_Attend_Date.My data type for Business_Day is DATE,other 2 column is DATETIME.The result should as below:

```
 Staff_ID  |       User_Attend_Date    |  Business_Day   |     Check_Same_Day
   S01     |   2013-05-01 15:18:45.537 |   2013-05-01    | 2013-05-01 15:18:45.537
   S01     |   2013-05-02 00:00:00.000 |   2013-05-01    | 2013-05-01 15:18:45.537
   S02     |   2013-05-03 06:20:30.225 |   2013-05-02    | 2013-05-03 06:20:30.225
```

I was try the following code,but fail to achieve the result.

```
SELECT *, Case WHEN DATEADD(hh, -3, User_Attend_Date)=Business_Day 
THEN User_Attend_Date ELSE BusinessDay END As 'Check_Same_Day' FROM tblAttendance
```

I was try use over partition but fail too.

```
DATEADD(hh, -3, User_Attend_Date) OVER (PARTITION BY BusinessDay) AS 'Check_Same_Day'
```

Hope someone can teach me.Thanks

Comment: If the values in 'business day' are just the year month day portion of 'user_attend_date' the column is redundant and not needed.  What are you really wanting to find?

Comment: I can't quite understand your expected results; how does the second row `2013-05-02 00:00:00.000 , 2013-05-01` become `2013-05-01 15:18:45.537`

Comment: That is because the staff may check-in twice.Therefore I need to minus 3 hours to check whether the staff is work in same business day. IF same business day, will use the first check-in datetime as Check_Same_Day This is the requirement of my client.Thanks

Comment: @HowardHee. I'm assuming you must have a user id on each row as well, and you want to do this for an a per-user basis? Have a look at the new edit for my answer. I have included a sql fiddle so you can quickly see what it does.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To change a datetime to the date it is on, use:

```
SELECT DATEADD(d, DATEDIFF(d, 0, GETDATE()), 0), GETDATE()
```

so in your case you coul use this to compare to `Business_Day`

```
SELECT Case WHEN DATEADD(d, DATEDIFF(d, 0, DATEADD(hour, -3, User_Attend_Date)), 0) = Business_Day
```

**EDIT**

You actually want to use the first login for any given day for a user, so you could use CTEs to achieve this. I have added an "expect" column (which you can easily remove), and I am assuming you must have a user_id to identify the users as well? If so then try:

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/c54b4/1

```
WITH AttendanceDate AS (
  SELECT User_Id, User_Attend_Date, Business_Day, DATEADD(d, DATEDIFF(d, 0, DATEADD(hour, -3, User_Attend_Date)), 0) AS ActualAttendDate
  FROM tblAttendance ),
FirstAttendance AS (
  SELECT User_Id, ActualAttendDate, MIN(User_Attend_Date) FirstLogin
  FROM AttendanceDate
  GROUP BY User_Id, ActualAttendDate
)
SELECT TA.User_Id, TA.User_Attend_Date, TA.Business_Day, FA.FirstLogin
FROM AttendanceDate AS TA
INNER JOIN FirstAttendance AS FA
    ON TA.User_Id = FA.User_Id
    AND TA.ActualAttendDate = FA.ActualAttendDate
```

Note that the cast is a little superfluous now: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/c54b4/2, and to see it with multiple users: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/4f2c7/1. The final result, without `Expect` as a column is on http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/e9e6c/1.

**EDIT 2**

And if you don't need the User_Id grouping, then its as simple as (http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/0daab/1):

```
WITH AttendanceDate AS (
  SELECT User_Attend_Date, Business_Day, DATEADD(d, DATEDIFF(d, 0, DATEADD(hour, -3, User_Attend_Date)), 0) AS ActualAttendDate
  FROM tblAttendance ),
FirstAttendance AS (
  SELECT ActualAttendDate, MIN(User_Attend_Date) FirstLogin
  FROM AttendanceDate
  GROUP BY ActualAttendDate
)
SELECT TA.User_Attend_Date, TA.Business_Day, FA.FirstLogin
FROM AttendanceDate AS TA
INNER JOIN FirstAttendance AS FA
    ON TA.ActualAttendDate = FA.ActualAttendDate
```

---

Original answer (no longer relevant based on new information explaining how the expected results are put together)

In full (http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/fa5bb/10):

```
SELECT User_Attend_Date, DATEADD(hour, -3, User_Attend_Date),
DATEADD(d, DATEDIFF(d, 0, DATEADD(hour, -3, User_Attend_Date)), 0) AS 'ForClarity1',
CAST(DATEADD(d, DATEDIFF(d, 0, DATEADD(hour, -3, User_Attend_Date)), 0) AS DATE) AS 'ForClarity2',
Business_Day AS 'ForClarity3',
 Case WHEN 
CAST(DATEADD(d, DATEDIFF(d, 0, DATEADD(hour, -3, User_Attend_Date)), 0) AS DATE) = Business_Day
 THEN User_Attend_Date ELSE Business_Day END As 'Check_Same_Day' 
FROM dbo.tblAttendance
```

Comment: I run the query in sqlfiddle, but the Check_Same_Day for second record is '2013-05-02 00:00:00.000', suppose is '2013-05-01 15:18:45.537'.Thanks

Comment: @HowardHee. I have updated with a new edit at the top, this uses CTEs and will work for you.

Comment: @HowardHee. And in case I have misunderstood, and you don't have a userId column (you aren't doing this for each user), then I have added a second edit without the userId column.

Comment: Your answer is working very well! Thank you for take your time explain to me.I really appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

I see two options:

1) DateDiff:

```
SELECT Case WHEN datediff(day,DATEADD(hh, -3, User_Attend_Date),Business_Day) < 1
THEN User_Attend_Date ELSE BusinessDay END As 'Check_Same_Day' FROM tblAttendance
```

2) Cast:

```
SELECT Case WHEN Cast(DATEADD(hh, -3, User_Attend_Date) as Date) = Business_Day
THEN User_Attend_Date ELSE BusinessDay END As 'Check_Same_Day' FROM tblAttendance
```

Answer (score 0):

You are almost there, the issue is that you need to convert the result of the DATEADD to a DATE (instead of DATETIME):

```
DECLARE @att TABLE
(
    User_Attend_Date DATETIME,
    Business_Day DATE
)

INSERT INTO @att
SELECT '2013-05-01 15:18:45.537', '2013-05-01'
UNION ALL
SELECT '2013-05-02 00:00:00.000', '2013-05-01'
UNION ALL
SELECT '2013-05-03 06:20:30.225', '2013-05-02'

SELECT 
    User_Attend_Date,
    Business_Day,
    CASE 
        WHEN CAST(DATEADD(hh, -3, User_Attend_Date) AS DATE) = Business_Day THEN User_Attend_Date
        ELSE Business_Day
    END AS 'Check_Same_Day'
FROM @att
```

This gives the result you're wanting, showing that two of the items matched your rule.

Answer (score 0):

You need to cast the first column(datetime) as date to compare with a date.

```
 SELECT 
      *,
      CASE WHEN  CAST(DATEADD(HOUR,-4,User_Attend_Date) AS DATE)=Business_Day
        THEN User_Attend_Date 
        ELSE Business_Day 
      END AS Check_Same_Day
      FROM #test
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it is displaying seconds values in row because ou have datatype DATE for Bussiness_day and datatype DATETIME for other column .

So It is possible to use DATE datatype in sql 2008 ?

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT  USER_ATTEND_DATE,SUBSTRING(CAST(BUSINESS_DAY AS VARCHAR(20)),0,13)AS BUSINESS_DAY,

        CASE 
            WHEN  DATEADD(hh, -3, User_Attend_Date) = Business_Day 
            THEN Business_Day
            ELSE DATEADD(hh, -3, User_Attend_Date)
        END CHECK_SAME_DAY
FROM attendance
```